# Select Option closes when hovering out of div on IE8 with jquery-ui-tabs

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-tabs

I'll try to be as specific as possible. I have an application that uses IE8 to load up an html page.

I have an html document that contains a form. Within the form are tabs (jquery-ui-tabs). Within the tabs when I click on a select (dropdown menu) and hover out of the box to choose an option, the options disappear before I can choose one (the sdropdown box is still in focus and I can use the arrow keys to change the selection).

It appears as though only some select elements are affected. It seems like there is some sort of onmouseleave code being triggered, but again only some dropdowns are affected and others work just fine.

In my head tag I have included a content="IE=edge"

I've seen this issue posted a lot of times before where a select option closes when the mouse leaves the div in IE8.

If I load the form in the actual IE8 browser then there is no problem with the select elements. 
If I remove the jquery ui tabs, then there is no problem with the select elements. 
If I change content="IE=edge" to content="IE=7", then there is no problem with the select elements (but this causes CSS issues)

As a stopgap I have implemented the jquery select-menu plugin. When implemented it prevents the dropdowns from closing when trying to select an option, but I will need to remove this plugin.

I'm hoping to find either a CSS or jquery solution to this issue.

Any ideas?